# Excel to create ID based on 2 or 3 cells (3rd cell is optional)

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 worksheets that I'm trying to compare.
Problem is that I can't go row by row because on the second worksheet there are extra entries based on "Batch Size", please see the example below. Also we can found duplicated data or missing ones on the second worksheet.

[example picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REFfZ.png)

I believe it would be a lot easier to find any discrepancies if I have the "Bolt ID"s already created on the first worksheet then just go down 1-by-1 on every row and find the corresponding row that includes the same "Bolt ID" somewhere on the second worksheet.

Based on Batch Size, if Batch Size = 0
Bolt ID = Program ID_Step Number

if Batch Size is bigger than 0 then (for example Batch Size = 4)

```
`Bolt ID = Program ID_Step Number_1
`Bolt ID = Program ID_Step Number_2
`Bolt ID = Program ID_Step Number_3
`Bolt ID = Program ID_Step Number_4`
```

Any help is much appreciated in advance
Thank you

Comment: Why do you exclude the batch size of zero?  If you include the batch size of 0 in your bolt id's then you will have consistent bolt ids to work with.

Comment: the second sheet is coming from a log file where the Bolt IDs are already created this way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@freeflow

Thank you, I've ended up adding "_0" to all "Bolt ID" where they were needed using the following formula:

```
=IF(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"_",""))>1,A1,IF(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"_","@",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"_",""))),2))<>"0",A1&"_0",A1))
```

Then I had the consistent "Bolt ID" to work with as you recommended and I could use this loop to compare my 2 sheets:

```
lastrow = steps.Range("A" & steps.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
counter = 2

Do While counter <= lastrow
    
    If Not steps.Range("A" & counter).EntireRow.Hidden Then
        
        sequence_id = steps.Range("A" & counter)
        step_no = steps.Range("B" & counter)
        descr = steps.Range("C" & counter)
        type_of_op = steps.Range("D" & counter)
        tool_id = steps.Range("E" & counter)
        batch_size = steps.Range("H" & counter)
                
            If steps.Range("C" & counter) <> "Scan Process Barcode" Then
                    
                If type_of_op = "Fastening" Then
                    fastening_id = 1
                    Else: fastening_id = 0
                End If
                
                Do While fastening_id <= batch_size
                    
                    bolt_id = sequence_id & "_" & step_no & "_" & fastening_id
                    
                    r = 0
                    With ActiveSheet.Range("P:P")
                        Set loc = .Cells.Find(bolt_id, , xlValues, xlWhole, , , True)
                        If loc Is Nothing Then
                            MsgBox bolt_id & " Not found"
                            Else
                                occured = 0
                                Do Until loc.Row <= r
                                    colorrange = (loc.Address)
                                    occured = occured + 1
                                    If occured >= 1 Then
                                        ActiveSheet.Range(colorrange).Interior.ColorIndex = 45
                                    End If
                                    r = loc.Row
                                    Set loc = .FindNext(loc)
                                Loop
                                If occured = 1 Then
                                    ActiveSheet.Range(colorrange).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
                                End If
                        End If
                    End With
                    fastening_id = fastening_id + 1
                Loop
                
           End If
    End If
counter = counter + 1
Loop
```

All it does is just highlighting the duplicated values for me but offsetting loc.address I can compare the rest of the cells and let the code making decisions.